# how do I update SQL columns with true or false based data in another column on the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, sql-update

Please see attached image

[image]

I would like to update `Supplier & Agent` Columns with either true or false, based on the info in the `Supplier_Agent` column. How would i do this?

Also, some records do not have any info in the `Supplier_Agent` column so for them, both `Supplier & Agent` Columns would be `FALSE`.

Comment: Can one row in this table be both a supplier and an agent? I suspect what you really should do is have a single column for SupplierType and a lookup table to indicate which type of supplier this is. That would be a better way to handle this type of thing.

Comment: Your suggestions sounds better. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 3):

make your agent and supplier column in `bit` datatype then do update

```
 update t
  set supplier=case when Supplier_Agent='Supplier'  then 1 else 0 end,
   agent =case when Supplier_Agent='Agent'  then 1 else 0 end
```

In sql server there is no boolean data type so 0 means `false` and 1 means `true`

Answer (score 2):

Use `case when`

```
update dbo.SuppliersNPD
set supplier= case when supplier_aggent='supplier' then 1 else 0 end,
agent= case when supplier_aggent='agent' then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: not sure why this has so many upvotes. The case expression is the right way to go but there is no such thing as true/false in t-sql. This is commonly handled with the bit datatype and 1/0.

Answer (score 0):

You should you the `case when` function, so you can set the value checking a specific condition.

```
update SNPD
set SNPD.supplier= case when SNPD.Supplier_Agent='Supplier' then 1 else 0 
end,
SNPD.Agent= case when SNPD.Supplier_Agent='Agent' then 1 else 0 end 
FROM SuppliersNPD as SNPD
```

I also recommend you to use enumeration instead of 'supplier' and 'agent' to identify the type of supplier. For example, you could have created a column called `Type` and use code `100` for suppliers and `200` for agents. This seems more complicated but makes the table easier to be maintained and it is often used in ERP software.